# Entire proof using BMCT to prove sequence convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Okay I know there is an answer somewhere else, but it does it a bit differently than that of my teacher and I'm trying to duplicate that way so could someone check if I'm right.

---

Question:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence defined by $$a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3 - a_n}, if n \geq 1$$

Does $\{a_n\}$ converge or diverge?

## My solution:

I just wrote down some terms.

$a_1 = 2, a_2 = 1, a_3 = \frac{1}{2}, a_4 = 5/13, a_5 = 13/34$. I claim this converges because its bounded below and strictly decreasing. BMCT states those are the condition for it to converge.

This is bounded below by $\frac{3- \sqrt{5}}{2}$. I got this by using this:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{3-a_n}$$ I would get two solutions for $a_n$, but this function is decreasing so its obvious which one to choose.

Claim: (1) Bounded below by $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and (2) strictly decreasing

Proof of (1)

WTS: $a_n \geq \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2} \forall n \in \mathbb N$

We will proceed by Induction

Consider $a_{k+1} = \frac{1}{3-a_k} \geq ??$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1)$

$a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{3-a_k}\geq \frac{1}{3-\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}}$ (by induction hypothesis)

hence $a_{k+1}\geq \frac{2}{3+\sqrt 5}$. Multiplying and dividing the RHS of the inequality by $3-\sqrt 5$ gives the desired inequality.

For $2)$, the main observation is that using induction you can prove that $a_n\leq \frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}$ (essentially by the same method used in $1)$). Hence you have

$0\geq (a_n-\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2})(a_n-\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2})$ which is true as the second term is positive and the first term is negative and hence their multiplication is negative.

Comment: Oh thank you. That makes a lot of sense. For 2), what I said good enough ?

Comment: @Tinler yes, but you need to give a reason that $why$ the first part is $\leq 0$, as I don't think so that it follows from $a_k\geq \frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}$.

Comment: Is that just saying how a positive times a negative is negative which makes the inequality hold?

Comment: Yes, you show that one of the term is always positive and the other is always negative.